# PROJECT_ID env and Secret Manager Access

Tags: google-cloud-build, google-secret-manager

I would like to use the Secret Manager to store a credential to our artifactory, within a cloud build step. I have it working using a build similar to:

```
steps:
- name: 'busybox:glibc'
  entrypoint: 'sh'
  args: ['-c', 'env']
  secretEnv: ['SECRET_VALUE']
availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
  - versionName: "projects/PROJECT_ID/secrets/TEST-SECRET/versions/1"
    env: 'SECRET_VALUE'
```

All great, no problems - I then try and slightly improve it to:

```
steps:
- name: 'busybox:glibc'
  entrypoint: 'sh'
  args: ['-c', 'env']
  secretEnv: ['SECRET_VALUE']
availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
  - versionName: "projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/TEST-SECRET/versions/1"
    env: 'SECRET_VALUE'
```

But then it throws the error:
`ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) INVALID_ARGUMENT: failed to get secret name from secret version "projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/TEST-SECRET/versions/1"`

I have been able to add a TRIGGER level env var (SECRET_MANAGER_PROJECT_ID), and that works fine. The only issue that as that is a trigger env, it is not available on rebuild, which breaks a lot of things.

Does anyone know how to get the PROJECT_ID of a Secret Manager from within CloudBuild without using a Trigger Param?

Comment: Have you tried `- versionName: projects/${PROJECT_ID}/secrets/TEST-SECRET/versions/1` (also I _think_ you can use `versions/lastest` instead of a specific version if that's at all useful)

Comment: yeah, I have tried that too:
`ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) INVALID_ARGUMENT: failed to get secret name from secret version "projects/${PROJECT_ID}/secrets/TEST-SECRET/versions/1`
feels like a very annoying edge case.

Comment: Under "Cloud Build" settings have you enabled "Secret Manager Accessor"? (Or followed [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/use-secrets#grant_permissions)?)

Comment: This is not currently supported.

Comment: incase anyone is wondering, I do not have the rep required to approve or even see the recommended edit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now, it's not possible to set dynamic value in the secret field. I already provided this feedback directly to the Google Cloud PM, it has been take into account, but I don't have more info to share, especially for the availability.

---

**EDIT 1**

*(January 22)*. Thanks to Seza443 comment, I tested again and now it works with automatically populated variable (PROJECT_ID and PROJECT_NUMBER), but also with customer defined substitution variables!

Comment: It is possible now; check answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/69273597/2179668

Comment: @seza443: Did you try?

Comment: Yes, I just ran a successful build using `$PROJECT_NUMBER` as a variable. :-)
Here how I wrote the reference to the secret in my cloudbuild.yaml: `projects/$PROJECT_NUMBER/secrets/DB_CONNECTION_STRING/versions/latest`

Comment: NIce improvement!

Comment: I had a try and I updated my answer. I didn't see that feature in the release notes, but it's a great news!

Answer (score 2):

It appears that Cloud Build now allows for the use of substitution variables within the `availableSecrets` field of a build configuration.

From Google Cloud's [documentation on using secrets](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/use-secrets#configuring_builds_to_access_the_secret_from):

> After all the build steps, add an `availableSecrets` field to specify the secret version and environment variables to use for your secret. **You can include substitution variables in the value of the `secretVersion` field.** You can specify more than one secret in a build.

I was able to use the `$PROJECT_ID` variable in my own build configuration like so:

```yaml
...
availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
    - versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/api-key/versions/latest
      env: API_KEY
```

Granted, there appears to be (at least at present) some discrepancy between the documentation quoted above and the recommended [configuration file schema](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema). In the documentation they refer to `secretVersion`, but that appears to have changed to `versionName`. In either case, it seems to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$PROJECT_NUMBER` instead.

https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values#using_default_substitutions

[image: Substituting built in env vars in GCB]